# Simplifying checking this win condition for tic tac toe and making it maintainable

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

```
def isWinner(self):
    for i in range(len(self.board)):
        if self.board[i][0]+self.board[i][1]+self.board[i][2]==(3*'X') or self.board[i][0]+self.board[i][1]+self.board[i][2]==(3*'O'):
            return True
        if self.board[0][i]+self.board[1][i]+self.board[2][i]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][i]+self.board[1][i]+self.board[2][i]==(3*'O'):
            return True

    if self.board[0][0]+self.board[2][2]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][0]+self.board[2][2]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'O'):
        return True
    if self.board[0][2]+self.board[2][0]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][2]+self.board[2][0]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'O'):
        return True

    return False
```

This function is supposed to return `True` if we get 3 * 'X's or 3 * 'O's and `False` elsewise in our tic Tac Toe board. It checks if we have a winner. However, based on the way I've currently made it, it does not allow for adding a larger size of the board. It currently operates under the assumption the board is 3*3. However, I'd like to change this so it functions for any N*N.

Does anyone have any suggestions to clean this up?

```
class ClassicTicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initializes an empty Numerical Tic Tac Toe board.
        Inputs: none
        Returns: None
        '''
        self.board = [] # list of lists, where each internal list represents a row
        self.size = 3   # number of columns and rows of board

        # populate the empty squares in board with empty string
        for i in range(self.size):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.size):
                row.append(' ')
            self.board.append(row)
        #print(self.board)

    def drawBoard(self):
        l1='    0   1   2'
        '''
        Displays the current state of the board, formatted with column and row
        indicies shown.
        Inputs: none
        Returns: None
        '''
        print(l1)
        for i in range(len(self.board)):
            print(' %d  %s | %s | %s' % (i,self.board[i][0],self.board[i][1],self.board[i][2]))
            print('   '+'-'*11)

    def squareIsEmpty(self, row, col):
        if self.board[row][col]==' ':
            return True
        return False
        '''
        Checks if a given square is empty, or if it already contains a number
        greater than 0.
        Inputs:
           row (int) - row index of square to check
           col (int) - column index of square to check
        Returns: True if square is empty; False otherwise
        '''

    # mark is a string for the users input of x or o
    def update(self, row, col, mark):
        if self.squareIsEmpty(row,col)==True:
            self.board[row][col]=mark.upper()
            return True

        if self.squareIsEmpty(row,col)==False:
            return False
        '''
        Assigns the integer, num, to the board at the provided row and column,
        but only if that square is empty.
        Inputs:
           row (int) - row index of square to update
           col (int) - column index of square to update
           num (string) - entry to place in square
        Returns: True if attempted update was successful; False otherwise
        '''

                def boardFull(self):
        '''
        Checks if the board has any remaining empty squares.
        Inputs: none
        Returns: True if the board has no empty squares (full); False otherwise
        '''
        nonempty_list=[]
        # TO DO: delete pass and complete method
        for i in self.board:
            # alternatively this could be range(len(self.board))
            for j in range(len(self.board)):
                if i[j]!=' ':
                    nonempty_list.append(i[j])

        if len(nonempty_list)<self.size**2:
            return False
        return True

    def isWinner(self):
        for i in range(len(self.board)):
            if self.board[i][0]+self.board[i][1]+self.board[i][2]==(3*'X') or self.board[i][0]+self.board[i][1]+self.board[i][2]==(3*'O'):
                return True
            if self.board[0][i]+self.board[1][i]+self.board[2][i]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][i]+self.board[1][i]+self.board[2][i]==(3*'O'):
                return True

        if self.board[0][0]+self.board[2][2]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][0]+self.board[2][2]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'O'):
            return True
        if self.board[0][2]+self.board[2][0]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'X') or self.board[0][2]+self.board[2][0]+self.board[1][1]==(3*'O'):
            return True
        return False

    def isNum(self):
        return False
        '''
        Checks whether the current player has just made a winning move.  In order
        to win, the player must have just completed a line (of 3 squares) that
        adds up to 15. That line can be horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.
        Inputs: none
        Returns: True if current player has won with their most recent move;
                 False otherwise
        '''
```

Comment: We're probably going to need the rest of the code.

Comment: @AMC Added the rest of the code to the end. Function in question is on top

Comment: Suggest you read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) especially if you want others to help you with your code. Note that your placement of function doc-strings is just plain wrong in a number of places (independent of the PEP8 recommendations regarding them).

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has excellent features to help avoid loops in these sorts of situations. An example, based on your code, to check to see if X or O had won separately is:

```
import numpy as np

def check_win(self, OX):        
    check = np.array(self.board)
    if max(np.count_nonzero(check == OX, axis=0)) == self.size or max(
            np.count_nonzero(check == OX, axis=1)) == self.size or np.count_nonzero(
        check.diagonal() == OX) == self.size or np.count_nonzero(
        np.fliplr(check).diagonal() == OX) == self.size:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It simply uses the Numpy features to check to see if the count of `OX` (i.e. `O` or `X` that you pass it) is equal to the size of the board (assuming you set `self.board_size` in your class.

So, if `size = 3`, it checks to see if any column or any row has 3 `OX` in it, then checks the two diagonals to see if they contain 3 `OX`. This would work with any size of board.

```
def isWinner(self):
    return any([self.check_win('X'), self.check_win('O')])
```

Would return `True` if either party had won, per your original requirement.